# Converting node js to python serial

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, pyserial

I am trying to convert some code in node js that reads data from a sensor to python code that can read it. The sensor is hi219m, in case that matters.

So far this part in node js

```
var SerialPort = require('serialport');  

var portName = 'com4'; 
var serialPort = new SerialPort("com4", {
                             autoOpen: false,
                             baudRate: 115200,  
                             dataBits: 8,    
                             parity: 'none',   
                             stopBits: 1
                          }, function(error){
                            console.log(error);
                          });
```

I can get to python with:

```
import serial

sensorSerial = serial.Serial('com4',115200,bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS,parity = serial.PARITY_NONE,stopbits =serial.STOPBITS_ONE)
```

There is this node js function for opening

```
serialPort.open(function(error){ 
   if(error){ 
     console.log("Error");
   }else{  
    console.log("Port Opened");
     serialPort.on('data',onData);
   }
});
```

In python I am thinking it just needs to be a while loop with reading the data to mimic `serialPort.on('data',onData);` and defining a function onData.

```
def onData():
```

So the main issue is understanding this part of the node js

```
var Struct = require('struct');

var msg     = Struct()
             .chars('frameStart',2)
             .word16Sle('len')
             .word16Sle('crc')
             .word16Sle('id')
             .chars('acc',1)
             .word16Sle('ax')
             .word16Sle('ay')
             .word16Sle('az')
             .chars('b0',1)
             .word16Sle('bx')
             .word16Sle('by')
             .word16Sle('bz')
             .chars('c0',1)
             .word16Sle('cx')
             .word16Sle('cy')
             .word16Sle('cz')
             .chars('d0',1)
             .word16Sle('Roll')
             .word16Sle('Pitch')
             .word16Sle('Yaw');

function onData(data){
  if(data.length == 41){ 
      msg._setBuff(data);
      var proxy = msg.fields;
      console.log("Roll:",proxy.Roll,"Pitch:",proxy.Pitch,"Yaw:",proxy.Yaw);
  }
}
```

In python I can read 41 bytes with `serial.read(41)`, but I am not sure how to get a specific msg and check if that message is 41, unless it is using `serial.readline()` and checking if that is 41?

Finally the main question in converting it is how the struct in python works, in particular, mimicking this part:

```
      msg._setBuff(data);
      var proxy = msg.fields;
```

Do I use `pack()` or is there another way?

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: Node's serial module is event-driven, so it fires whenever it receives data. Python's `serial.read` is imperative. They're different programming paradigms

Comment: I understand that point, so it would be helpful if someone could explain how to adapt python serial to achieve it. More importantly, I am trying to understand the struct system.  Python gets a string from serial when I use type(), so I am not sure how the struct works.